# What is the timeline for updating MS Accessibility Insights to use axe-core 4.8.n?

Tags: accessibility-insights

I see that MS Accessibility Insights claims to cover WCAG 2.2, which it does via manual checks. However, it does not run the automatic check for target size that was added as part of axe-core 4.8 in Sept 2023. My question is when will Accessibility Insights axe-core version (currently 4.7.2) next be updated to include target size among the automated tests, as per v4.8.0 onwards. More generally, what is the normal lag between a new version of axe-core being released, and Accessibility Insights catching up?
Thanks